# Differentiating by $\ln$ of $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I wanted to differentiate $\ln (\alpha x)$ by $\ln x$. I guess I know how to differentiate this function by $x$ by applying the chain rule such that

$$\frac{d}{d x} \ln (\alpha x) = \frac{\partial \ln u}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x},$$

where $u = \alpha x$.

Then, to differentiate $\ln (\alpha x)$ by $\ln x$, I made a change of variable with $z= \ln x$ such that $u = \alpha \exp z$. So,

$$\frac{d}{d \ln x} \ln (\alpha x) = \frac{d}{d z} \ln (\alpha \exp z) = 1. $$

I guess this is correct but is it rigorous enough? Is there a more direct way to differentiate this function without a change of variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. A more direct way is $\frac d{d(\ln x)} \ln \alpha x = \frac d{d(\ln x)} \ln \alpha  + \frac d{d(\ln x)} \ln x = 0 +1=1$ as  $\ln \alpha$ is a constant.

It is assumed that both $\alpha$ and $x$ take positive values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct yet the argument is a little cumbersome. Perhaps it'd be easier as follows:

$$\frac{d(\ln(ax))}{d(\ln x)}=\frac{d\left(\ln a+\ln x\right)}{d(\ln x)}=\frac{d(\ln a)}{d(\ln x)}+\frac{d(\ln x)}{d(\ln x)}=0+1=1$$

Of course, assuming $\;a,\,x>0\;$

Comment: Thank you! It is unfortunate that I cannot accept more than one answer! I don't want to be too picky, but I think there is one missing ")" after `d(ln(ax)`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You are correct, below is how I would have shown it.

Let $u = \ln x$ such that $x = \exp(u)$. Then using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule),
$$
\frac{d}{du} [\ln (\alpha \exp{u})] = \frac{1}{\alpha \exp{u}} \frac{d}{du} [\alpha \exp u] = \frac{\alpha \exp{u}}{\alpha \exp {u}} = 1.
$$
We could find this easier by using that
$$
\ln{\alpha x} = \ln{\alpha} + \ln{x} = \ln{\alpha} + u
$$
for which the derivative is
$$\frac{d}{du}[ \ln \alpha + u] = 0 + 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you! It is unfortunate that I cannot accept more than one answer!

Comment: No problem, just glad to be of help!